# How to declare array in format where continuous zeros can be written as n*0 like in fortran?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a fortran array of the type

`DATA ELEV \1.2,3.2,2*0.0,3.9,3*0.0\`

which in python would be

`ELEV = [1.2, 3.2, 0.0, 0.0, 3.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

Notice how 2*0.0 was not 0.0 but instead 2 elements with value 0.0.

Is there some way to use numpy or other python methods(or libraries) to **write it similarly** in python3 ?

I essentially have array in the fortran format which I want to use in my python code instead of mere representation.

Comment: If you really want something as much like the Fortran array literal format as possible, you can write something that parses exactly the Fortran format. If you only want this for arrays of literal values, and it's just going to be short-ish literals it's pretty trivial. (If you want it for arrays of variables, possibly together with other Python features like unpacking, then you're probably talking about a complicated design and a painful import hook or something, so I wouldn't bother.)

Comment: **@fireball**, I think writing a reusable code for inline insertion of sequence of same numbers would be a great fit (instead of dividing a list into sub lists and using **+** operator again and again) which can do using **unpacking** feature of lists. Please have a look at my answer. I think you will like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [new `*` unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) and list multiplication.

```
>>> [1.2, 3.2, *2*[0.0], 3.9, *3*[0.0]]
[1.2, 3.2, 0.0, 0.0, 3.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

You can also multiply strings and tuples in Python.

```
>>> 'abc'*3
'abcabcabc'
>>> (1, 2, 3)*2
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

You can unpack any iterable, and this also works in tuple displays, etc.

```
>>> (1.2, 3.2, *'xy'*2, 3.9, *3*(0.0,), *'foo')
(1.2, 3.2, 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 3.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'f', 'o', 'o')
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in lists already have a very similar functionality:

```
[1.2, 3.2] + [0.0] * 2 + [3.9] + [0.0] * 3
```

results in

```
[1.2, 3.2, 0.0, 0.0, 3.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful however gilch's answer was even easier to implement.

Comment: @fireball.1 Syntax in `gilch`s answer is also new to me. Nice! I guess it might depend on the Python version whether it supports `*n*[...]` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most natural way of doing this in `numpy` is with the `repeat` function/method:

```
In [252]: a = np.array([1.2,3.2,0,3.9,0])
In [253]: b = a.repeat([1,1,2,1,3])
In [254]: b
Out[254]: array([1.2, 3.2, 0. , 0. , 3.9, 0. , 0. , 0. ])
```

or if there are a lot of 0s, copy the nonzero values to a zeros array

```
In [255]: c = np.zeros(8, float)
In [256]: c[[0,1,4]] = [1.2,3.2,3.9]
In [257]: c
Out[257]: array([1.2, 3.2, 0. , 0. , 3.9, 0. , 0. , 0. ])
```

Answer (score -1):

**@fireball**, I think it's better if you will have a reusable code block (function) for this.

> Here it is **get_nums()**, which takes 2 parameters.
>
> First parameter **n** is the number we want to repeat and second parameter **freq** denotes frequency of **n**.
>
> Function returns a list containing **n**, **freq** times which we unpack in the calling statement using *****.

Here you don't need to use **+** operator again and again multiple times and divide the list in multiple sub lists like below.

> [65, 54] + [0.0] * 5 + [6, 9]

Please have a look at the below python code and its output.

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/AJDEUE76668

```
def get_nums(n, freq):
   l = [n] * freq
   return l

# TEST CASE 1
ELEV = [1.2, 3.2, *get_nums(0.0, 2) ,3.9, *get_nums(0.0, 3)]
print(ELEV)
print() # newline

# TEST CASE 2
arr = [45, *get_nums(1, 4), *get_nums(9, 3), 34, 99, *get_nums(7, 1), 12, 21, *get_nums(-1, 5)]
print(arr)
```

#### Output »

```
[1.2, 3.2, 0.0, 0.0, 3.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

[45, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 34, 99, 7, 12, 21, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: This isn't useful for my problem since the array is already mentioned in the fortran format and to use this method, I'd have to re-write the arrays.